# Problem With Bionicle Joint Sockets Cracking, Repair Options?

Tags: technic, repair, bionicle, replacement-parts

I'm pretty sure that serious *Bionicle* fans have all dealt with cracking of the joint socket pieces. However, is super-gluing the broken parts a solution? I'm worried that the joint  socket won't be elastic enough for the joint piece to enter, or even that it might crack again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super-glue? Nope, no super-gluing if *LEGO* has anything to say about it.

This is probably a duplicate question, but if you contact *LEGO* directly, they will replace the part for free.  Follow this [older post for details](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1801/how-does-lego-handle-the-breakage-of-hero-factory-sockets).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I think that it is very ulikely they will replace parts of the set that is now a decade old (I'm speaking of 8994). Unfortunately I do not have credit card nor paypal either (I'm 16 years old) and can't buy online using their pick-a-brick service. Again thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

The socket joints from around 2008-2010 were poorly designed. They were both too thin and too tight, so cracking was a very common problem.

Because the issue is the shape of the part, super glue doesn't do much. I tested it out on of my broken joints and the parts cracked again the first time I connected it. So don't bother with that.

What may help is sanding the inside of the socket's prongs down to make it less tight during insertion. I tested this out on a few of my sockets. Sanded sockets took 100 insertions without cracking while the ones that weren't broke after 20-30. However, I've also heard that the 2008 joints crack after sitting too long in a connected state, which sanding may not prevent.